# SQL-Server 2008, SQL to replace nulls with zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have multiple columns in my table that have a NULL value.

I want to replace all of the `NULL` values in this table with a `0`.

Comment: Try get some knowledge about `UPDATE` statement http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all of you columns being of a numeric data type, you can do this:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Column1 = ISNULL(Column1,0),
    Column2 = ISNULL(Column2,0),
    Column3 = ISNULL(Column3,0),
    Column4 = ISNULL(Column4,0)....
```